# Need assistance using an || operator in a Javascript statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got a Wordpress theme with some Javascript in it that relates to product variation dropdowns in WooCommerce. Basically this Javascript statement appears to simply look at the selected values of each drop down and then passes the values to the rest of the script which in turn changes some of the product details on the page.

The statement that looks at values of the dropdowns is below:

```
if ((this.attributes[wd_selected_color_name] &&  
     this.attributes[wd_selected_color_name] === wd_selected_color) &&
   (this.attributes[wd_selected_housing_name] &&  
    this.attributes[wd_selected_housing_name] === wd_selected_housing)) {
```

This works perfectly fine except not all of my products have just two dropdowns. Some have three and in those cases, the Javascript doesn't trigger and the values don't change on the page.

That said, although I have a very limited knowledge of Javascript, I was able to cobble together the following statement that works for just those occasions:

```
if( 
(this.attributes[ wd_selected_color_name ] && this.attributes[  wd_selected_color_name ] === wd_selected_color) && (this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] === wd_selected_housing) &&  (this.attributes[ wd_selected_voltage_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_voltage_name ] === wd_selected_voltage) )
) {
```

Problem is, this breaks all products with only two drop downs. So I actually need a single statement flexible enough to handle both circumstances. I thought I knew how to write it using an || operator but apparently I was wrong because the following code does not work:

```
if(
( (this.attributes[ wd_selected_color_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_color_name ] === wd_selected_color) && (this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] === wd_selected_housing) )|| ( (this.attributes[ wd_selected_color_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_color_name ] === wd_selected_color) && (this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_housing_name ] === wd_selected_housing) && (this.attributes[ wd_selected_voltage_name ] && this.attributes[ wd_selected_voltage_name ] === wd_selected_voltage) )
) {
```

In this case only the statement before the || gets triggered. I've verified this by swapping the statements' positions. Whatever one comes first works and the other one gets ignored.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Does it have something to do with how I'm nesting the parenthesis?

Comment: Your first condition would always be true, and since logical OR || evaluates the left condition and doesn't evaluate the 2nd one, the 2nd condition would never be checked. In your case, if 2nd condition is true, then 1st is also true and the 2nd would be simply skipped ...

Comment: You can simplify your logic and code maintainability by breaking the components into variables. I get the following `if(isColor && isHousing || isColor && isHousing && isVoltage)` which doesn't make sense because if the first doesn't pass the second won't either. http://jsbin.com/xumejes/edit?js,output

Comment: Which is the same as `if(isColor && isHousing)`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So I'm actually going about this the wrong way altogether since one of my statements will always be true. That said, is there a better way to get this working?

Comment: For what it's worth, your variable version does simplify things quite a bit. But like you said, since the first statement is always true the second one gets ignored. With that in mind is there any way to detect/flag if the isVoltage dropdown exists and approach it from that angle instead? It will always be the third menu in the event that three menus exist.

Comment: I don't know what your code wants to do or what the variables mean. At first glance it looks like we're in an event handler which means `this` is a dropdown that just changed. maybe wd_selected_color_name is an attr that only exists on one dropdowns, but then how would this also equal both the wd_selected_color and wd_selected_housing values? At what point does wd_selected_color, wd_selected_housing etc. get set, what are those values, etc.? I can take guesses at what you're trying to do, but you need to spell it out better in a snippet or on jsbin/plunker for anyone to really help. :(